# SubscribeOn and observeOn in the main thread

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I´m trying to use subscribeOn and obsereOn with an Executor to allow me back to the main thread once the async task finish.
I end up with this code but it does not work

```
@Test
    public void testBackToMainThread() throws InterruptedException {
        processValue(1);
        processValue(2);
        processValue(3);
        processValue(4);
        processValue(5);
//        while (tasks.size() != 0) {
//            tasks.take().run();
//        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();


    private void processValue(int value) throws InterruptedException {
        Observable.just(value)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext(number -> processExecution())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.from(command -> tasks.add(command)))
                .subscribe(x -> System.out.println("Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value:" + x));
        tasks.take().run();
    }

    private void processExecution() {
        System.out.println("Execution in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to accomplish what I want?

When I run I only printing

```
Execution in RxIoScheduler-2
Execution in RxIoScheduler-3
Execution in RxIoScheduler-4
Execution in RxIoScheduler-5
Execution in RxIoScheduler-6
done
```

Regards

Comment: I run your code and it output as my expect. What's your question?

Comment: The print Thread: never happens only the executions in: and then done

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand you.

Comment: Do you see this Console print?? println("Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value:" + x)

Comment: It will print `main` because you always take and run the task in main thread.

Comment: could you please paste your console log?. I update my question to show you what my execution print. Thanks

Comment: @DeanXu Sorry now I paste my output, please could you share yours

Comment: My output is different with yours. I think it is because I use RxJava2 and you use RxJava. I will take a look by RxJava.

Comment: @akarnokd Is this a bug of RxJava? Can you help us?

Comment: @DeanXu by now, assuming something is a bug in RxJava should be among the last thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you can't know how many tasks should be executed at a given time and also not deadlock on waiting for tasks that should happen after you unblock the main thread.

Returning to the Java main thread is not supported by any extension to 1.x I know. For 2.x, there is the [BlockingScheduler](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#blockingscheduler) from the extensions project that allows you to do that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockingScheduler scheduler = new BlockingScheduler();

    scheduler.execute(() -> {
        Flowable.range(1,10)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(scheduler)
        .doAfterTerminate(() -> scheduler.shutdown())
        .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v + " on " + Thread.currentThread()));
    });

    System.out.println("BlockingScheduler finished");
}
```

Note the call to `scheduler.shutdown()` which has to be called eventually to release the main thread, otherwise your program may never terminate.

Comment: I tried your aproach, but it´s seems is running sequentially. Can you take a look to my second post?.

Answer (score 1):

**Your question will not happen in RxJava2. It's recommanded to use RxJava2.**

I compared RxJava-1.2.7 and RxJava-2.0.7 and found the root cause. And now I am looking for the solution.

In RxJava-1.2.7.You can see `ObservableObserveOn#145` and find it `schedule` the task when you call `request`. It means it will call `Executor.execute` when you subscribe on it. So your task queue accept the `Runnable` immediately. And then you take and run the `Runnable` (which is actual `ExecutorSchedulerWorker`) but the upstream's `onNext` haven't been called (because you sleep 2000ms). It will return `null` on `ObserveOnSubscriber#213`. When upstream call `onNext(Integer)`, the task will never be run.

Comment: I think the title is not well formed. Sorry but still don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate an example please? Thanks!

Comment: @paul I can give you a quick solution. Repeat `tasks.take().run()` twice and then you will see the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just update my code with suggestion of akanord but this aproach it seems to block one task to the other, and just end up running sequential.

With the code:

```
   @Test
    public void testBackToMainThread() throws InterruptedException {
        processValue(1);
        processValue(2);
        processValue(3);
        processValue(4);
        processValue(5);
        System.out.println("done");
    }

    private void processValue(int value) throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingScheduler scheduler = new BlockingScheduler();
        scheduler.execute(() -> Flowable.just(value)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext(number -> processExecution())
                .observeOn(scheduler)
                .doAfterTerminate(() -> scheduler.shutdown())
                .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v + " on " + Thread.currentThread())));
    }

    private void processExecution() {
        System.out.println("Execution in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the output

```
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
1 on Thread[main,5,main]
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2 on Thread[main,5,main]
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
3 on Thread[main,5,main]
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
4 on Thread[main,5,main]
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
5 on Thread[main,5,main]
done
```

What I want to achieve is this output

```
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
1 on Thread[main,5,main]
2 on Thread[main,5,main]
3 on Thread[main,5,main]
4 on Thread[main,5,main]
5 on Thread[main,5,main]
done
```

So every time the main thread run the pipeline run the onNext in another thread and then it return from the method until the another thread finish and make it the main thread back to the pipeline.

Comment: You have to encompass all tasks with the blocking scheduler and not individually create a blocking scheduler for each item.

Comment: If I define the BlockingScheduler as global scope only the first task it´s executed.  Execution in RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
1 on Thread[main,5,main]
done  I´m start thinking that what I want dont even has any sense. The main thread have to wait for the future at some point anyway.